# ADB Wireless + Windows + Non-rooted Device + Hang Issue

Tags: android, windows, wifi, adb, wireless

I am trying to connect my device via WiFi and following the steps mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless).
But when I **restart adb** in different modes like:
1- `adb usb`, or

2- `adb tcpip 5555`

the result is like:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
```

And it hangs there itself, nothing happens after that.

Is something else needed that I am missing ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, if someone read my question and tried for some solution but I found a work-around solution for this:

1. Run the command `adb tcpip 5555` and when it hangs, disconnect the USB

2. Connect the USB again, run the command again, now you can see that it proceeds to next input line where you can proceed to `adb connect **.**.**.**` command to connect to device via tcp.

3. Now, just remove the USB cable and continue using the device.

NOTE: Device and System must be connected to same wireless network.